# Can't see all survey responses with Full Control

Tags: survey, response

I have created a survey with one branching question and allow other to fill out the survey with the Contribute permission. I have the Full Control permission but somehow cannot see all responses, only my own. Does anyone know how I can see all responses and use the data?

Comment: Update: I can see 1 response at this moment (which isn't my own), but the number of responses is 7 already

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you have full control on list? Is inheritance is broken on this list, please check again from list settings.

Comment: Thanks to you both. 

I am using Sharepoint 2013. And yes I am sure I have Full Control. 

Could it be that the difference in Number of responses and actual responses I can see is due to people cancelling their response?

Comment: You should be able to see all completed responses under All responses in survey.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Ganesh's comments - check the Survey permissions.  Broken inheritance (permissions exceptions) sounds like the probable cause for your issue.

[image: Check the Permissions]

Perhaps it's also worth checking the Advanced Settings, though since you have Full Control, you should be able to see everything regardless of these settings.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because SharePoint does not show incomplete surveys on the Show all responses view.

[Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2019395/the-survey-count-differs-between-number-of-responses-and-show-all-resp)

**Resolution**

This behavior is by design. To avoid this problem, make sure that users click the Finish button in the survey.

Answer (score 0):

Probable causes to your issue:

1. **Broken Inheritance on Survey**:

   Please Check the permissions on your Survey app. Follow below steps to check the permissions:

   1. Go to Survey Settings.
   2. Click on **Permissions for this survey**.
   3. Click on **Check Permissions** option Under **PERMISSIONS** tab in top ribbon.
   4. Enter your name and click on **Check Now**. You can check your permissions here.
2. **Item-Level Permissions**:(If you can see 1 response this is not the case for you.)

   To check the Item-Level permissions, follow below steps:

   1. Go to Survey Settings.
   2. Click on **Advanced Settings**.
   3. Check the radio button selected under **Read access** option, it should be **Read all responses** in order to see the all responses to the survey.